# Absolute relative positioning

Tags: css

My client gave me access to change just a part of his HTML and its like:

```
<div style="position:relative;">PUT YOUR CODE HERE</div>
```

The problem is that I need to put an absolute div left:0px and top:0px to stick in the top of the page but instead it sticks relative to the  above.

Can I, being inside a relative div, position absolute elements to the window and not the parent relative div with just css without using any other trick? I mean, I dont want to use JS to calculate the top/left position of the relative and then subtract it from my inside absolute div.

Thank you.

Comment: cant you use `position:fixed;` if you want it stuck at top left of page?

Comment: thank you but I need the div to be scrolable with the page and if I use fixed it will never disappear when the user scrolls down.

Comment: No you can't. An element will always be positioned according to the first parent that has a `position`.

Comment: So you are sure I cant solve this problem @putvande ? Cause, if you are sure I will have to make major changes in my clients website and it will be much harder than if there was a solution. Just want to make sure ok?

Comment: Not without JavaScript. Or you can set `top:-Xpx` but that is not a good solution.

Comment: Can't you just move that `div` up? Like being the first visible element, so it doesn't stick to its parent?

Comment: @Renan I cant move it up. I really have to introduce my code only inside that f** relative div. That's amazing how a simple problem will end up with a nasty solution - JS.

Comment: A negative `top` would do it

Comment: You said you wanted to avoid using JS to calculate the parent's position, etc., which is probably wise. Can you use JS to just *create* a new div, attach it to `body` element, add absolute positioning, etc.?  (rather than styling literal, inline HTML)

Comment: If the content is limited and you can add a few styles: http://jsfiddle.net/4ksgW/1/. If you need to add more than can be done with a pseudo-element, you are probably out of luck for a CSS-only solution.

Comment: If the parent container has overflow set to hidden, the negative pixels wouldn't work. Considering the inline styles, the doesn't seem to be an issue, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

No; not unless you know the distance to the top-left corner in which case you could use a negative `top:` and `left:` value.

Absolute positioning is relative to the closest ancestor with a non-static position.